# How can I make this dot-matrix in Figma without doing it dot-by-dot?

Tags: sketch-app, figma

[image: The grid in the background here]

Ideally I'd like it to follow a bezier path so I can change the shape and find what I like best.

Comment: I am not a Sketch/Figma user, however in other vector software such as Illustrator or Inkscape, you could [set a dotted stroke on multiple Bézier curves](https://imgur.com/a/dK2JmJJ).  I'd be surprised if this isn't also possible in Sketch too.

Comment: @BillyKerr I was just as surprised to find out that it's not possible in Figma

Comment: By the way this is not a dot matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_matrix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I have also faced this problem and come to a solution, which may help you:

1. Open Figma.
2. Draw a rectangle
3. Select a pen tool with <kbd>P</kbd> on your keyboard or  the help of mouse.
4. Draw desired shape with your pen tool
5. Go to the right-hand side toolbar and select *stroke*, and then follow below steps in *stroke* field.
6. Increase the width of the line by dragging with the mouse right or by typing number with your keyboard. In my example, 5 was suitable.
7. Now click to the menu bar (three dots), and change CAP option from *None* to *Round.*
8. And finally, fill the *Daskes* field with *[dash, gap]*. 1,20 was suitable for me.

I created a [video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UzMpIQ4Bc3w&feature=youtu.be) for more clarification.

Comment: Thanks, @wrzlprmft, for improving this answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's (surprisingly) not possible to do in Figma. You can do it in Sketch the same way as Illustrator:

1. Draw a path with the Vector tool (<kbd>V</kbd>) or Pencil tool (<kbd>P</kbd>) - preferably the Vector tool, with which you can just add a few points and you have a more precise control of the line
2. Adjust the Thickness value in the Borders panel - that will be the size of the dot.
3. click the Cog icon in Borders and select round Ends, round Joints and adjust Dash & Gap values: Dash will be the dot (use **1** to make it a circle) and Gap will be the distance between the dots (it will depend on the length / thickness of your line)
4. duplicate the line and adjust the shapes / positions
5. Optional step: Adjust the Opacity of the lines (in your example the further lines to the right have lower opacity value)

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it with Figma but it's possible with Sketch:

Install Sketch
Install Looper plugin via this link: http://sureskumar.com/looper
Create your desired shape
Convert it to Figma
Enjoy it:)

1. Install Sketch
2. Install Looper plugin via this link: http://sureskumar.com/looper
3. Create your desired shape ( here is some tutorial to do this: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzm9iVAvS9rVn5ZyZSbrIVQ/videos)
4. Convert it to Figma
5. Enjoy it:)

Figma is a great plugin to make complicated designs and I'm sure it can help you.

Comment: you don't need a plugin to do this, and your answer is really vague (dl plugin / watch one of these tutorial videos - which one?). Check [answer] to learn what constitutes a good answer.